# Need some CSS guidance

Tags: css

I am trying to make two custom fields of a checkout form appear next to each other. I can get them next to each other, however, the field below them are overlapping.

I have tried to use the `clear: both/left/right;` to fix this but it doesn't seem to work as I need it to. I have also tried `display: block/inline/inline-block;` to try to force the element below onto a new line.

Any suggestions?

```
.pract_county, .pract_postcode {
float: left;
margin-right: 47px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please create snippet so someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I added the CSS snippet above.

Comment: We need your html too please - see how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is you could simply add a line break tag after the second (Postal Code) input to create a line break. See link below.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

If you would prefer to use only CSS you could set the form headers to 100% width so that they need to move to the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The solution was so simple I completely overlooked it. Adding a <br/> did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
    height:20px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:2px;
    width:90%;
}


<p>Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Name">  </p>
<p>Subject:<input type="text" placeholder="Subject">  </p>
<p>E-Mail:<input type="email" placeholder="E-Mail">  </p>
```